# Memory Leak on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory-leaks, exoplayer

I'm using Eclipse's Memory Analyzer to analyze a heap dump for my app which use ExoPlayer. I have detected 2 suspects:

**One instance of "com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$InternalTrackOutput" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4188d798" occupies 9.501.856 (42,46%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque" loaded by "".**

**One instance of "com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4188d798" occupies 7.062.536 (31,56%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque" loaded by "".**

What is the problem and what could be the solution possible? I am new using this tool of Eclipse, and I have problems with the memory used by my app.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide the code in which exoplayer is used please.

Comment: player = new DemoPlayer(new ExtractorRendererBuilder(MainActivity.getContext(),userAgent, Uri.parse(forceUrl)));
   
   player.prepare();
   player.setSurface(MainActivity.getSurface_live());
   player.setPlayWhenReady(true);